# Regex Match first occurrence

Tags: regex

I have a huge text file containing various articles and I am trying to extract lines from it using regex. I know that the line below the title starts either with For/From (most of the times) I wrote the following regex but if there are articles that have paragraphs starting with From/For, it matches the title until the paragraph. How do I make the regex match the very first occurrence of For/From?

```
((?<=\n)[A-Z].*\n+(?=(?:(?:From)|(?:For))))
```

Comment: Please tell us the format of this document, is it HTML?  Can you give us an example of a piece of the document that you would like to get to match, but which matches incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Make your quantifier non-greedy.

```
((?<=\n)[A-Z].*?\n+(?=(?:(?:From)|(?:For))))
               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you are using the `/g` flag.  It is possible that removing that may fix your problem, as you don't want to match all occurrences, only the first one.